# Google Calendar API for a simple script

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to get a simple script (python) to work against the google calendar API and don't seem to be able to get the authentication to work properly. Its for a basic raspberry pi based thing I'm trying to make at home, and I need to just grab all the events from my google calendar.

I started with the code examples on the website, but because my script is totally server side, There was no way I could get the auth challenge step to work properly (it tried with `lynx`, but didn't work)

I then found examples with a service account - which seemed like the right thing as it didn't need the challenge flow. Furthermore, getting the creds_with_subject, seemed like the right approach to actually get a token related to the google account that owns the calendar. I think I got it all strung together, but then I don't actually get anything listed (as a start, I was using the `calendar.list()` endpoint to list the calendars out). The authentication step seemed to work (no errors) - but the ensuing list was empty. I'm guessing because my service account token wasn't associated/allowed to access my google account calendar. I've enabled the calendar API in the project to which the service account belongs.

Many of the guides I found seem to mention GSuite, which its not clear if I need

So summary questions:

- For this type of usage - is the service account the right approach?
- If so, do I need to associate this service account with my google account (that actually owns the calendar)?
- It looks like the simple API key work doesn't work any more, but thought I'd check in case there is a simpler way?
- do I need GSuite?

```
from __future__ import print_function
import datetime
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google.oauth2 import service_account



SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Google Calendar API.
    Prints the start and name of the next 10 events on the user's calendar.
    """
    creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file("credentials.json", scopes=SCOPES);
    creds_with_subjects = creds.with_subject("<my real account>@gmail.com");

    print(creds);
    print(creds_with_subjects);
    service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=creds_with_subjects)
    print(creds);

    print("Getting Calendar list");
    page_token = None
    while True:
      calendar_list = service.calendarList().list(pageToken=page_token).execute()
      print(calendar_list);
      page_token = calendar_list.get('nextPageToken')
      if not page_token:
        break


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Creating a service account is not enough. You also have to perform domain wide delegation and impersonate your user.

The main purpose of granting domain-wide authority to a *service account* is for these accounts to be able to access data on behalf of a user in your domain as otherwise the *service account* acts like just another account and it is trying to access **its own data** from Calendar, hence the empty response you are receiving.

To impersonate your user, you will have to follow the steps below:

1. Create a `Credentials` object from the service account's credentials and the scopes your application needs access to:

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account

SCOPES = ['SCOPE1', 'SCOPE2', ...]
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = '/path/to/service.json'

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
```

2. Delegate domain-wide authority:

```
delegated_credentials = credentials.with_subject('YOURADDRESS@DOMAIN.COM')
```

However, in order to do this, you need to have a Google Workspace domain.

#### Reference

- [Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#python);
- [Authorizing Requests to the Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/auth).

Comment: Thanks for the response, I think I’m stuck as I don’t have a way to create a google workspace domain just for my simple use case (at least not one that’s free) - so I will look for another way to do this.